# Alamofire cancel download on destination error

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am working on a project and trying to figure out if my download destination may fail.

As an example, if the destination URL or path fails to be clear because it already exists, I would like to handle this and prevent the request to be made.

Is there a simple way to stop a download request while in the destination closure ?

```
Alamofire
        .download(
            .GET,
            url,
            destination:{
                (temporaryURL, response) in
                let manager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
                let directoryURL = manager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
                let pathComponent = response.suggestedFilename
                let localPath = directoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier ?? "Default", isDirectory:true).URLByAppendingPathComponent(pathComponent!)

                if (manager.fileExistsAtPath(localPath!.path!)) {
                    do {
                        try manager.removeItemAtURL(localPath!)
                    } catch let error {
                        print(error)
                        ==> 
                       HOW CAN I GET THIS TO STOP THE DOWNLOAD 
                       AND CALL RESPONSE WITH AN ERROR 
                       <==
                    }
                }
                return localPath!
            }
        )
        .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
        .response {
            ...
    };
```

As a bonus, I'd love to be able to send this to the response closure as an error, which would make error handling way easier.